# Delete Related Row Laravel [Unknown column 'users.pasien_id' in 'where clause']

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I tried to delete the corresponding row.

Pasien table dam Users table

When I delete a row in a pasien table, the rows that are connected to the users table should also be deleted. However, this shows an error that makes me confused, whether I incorrectly implemented belongsTo and hasMany on the model.

I have tried to reverse it (belongsTo and hasMany), but it's still an error. What is the correct line of code for this problem?

Users Table

- id
- name
- email
- password

Pasien Table

- id
- iduser
- status

**Pasien model**

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Users');
    }
public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();
      static::deleting(function($pasien) {
        $pasien->users()->delete();
      });
  }
```

**User model**

```
public function pasien()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Pasien');
    }
```

**Pasien controller**

```
public function destroy(Pasien $pasien)
    {
        $pasien->delete();

        return redirect()->route('pasien.index')
        ->with('success','Pasien deleted successfully');
    }
```

Comment: A `Pasien` belongs to an `User` and a `User` has many `Pasien`. Is that correct?

Comment: Provide the foreign key to `hasMany` and `belongsTo` methods, the default should be `user_id` by convention but yours is `iduser` so you should provide it (`hasMany('App\User', 'iduser')`, `belongsTo('App\Pasien', 'iduser')`)

Comment: Yes ... I got it. Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that foreign key `iduser` in `Pasiens` table doesn't follow the convention that laravel follows (it expect the column name to be `user_id` as it points to `Users` table)

As mentioned in the docs [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

> By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id.

To solve the problem you have to provide your custom foreign key name to `belongsTo` and `hasMany`, so laravel can determine the relationship between the two tables correctly.

In **User** model

```php
public function pasien()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pasien', 'iduser');
}
```

And in **Pasien** model

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Users', 'iduser');
}
```